# How to make a property of a Parse Installation object be a pointer to a User object?

Tags: ios, objective-c, pointers, parse-platform

Currently, when a user opens my Parse app for the first time, a new `Installation` object is created on the Parse database with their `installationId` and other properties.

Once they log in, it updates this `Installation` object's `userId` property  with the `objectId` string of that person's `User` object. It's nothing more than a string that happens to be equivalent to the respective `User`s objectId though, what I want is for it to also be a pointer to that `User` object.

I've tried setting the `userId` property to be a pointer instead of a string from the website, but this gives me an error from the app stating `Error: invalid type for key userId, expected object, but got string`, because my iOS code is sending it over as a string, and not as a pointer to the `User` class.

How can I make the userId string point to the `User` class from my code? The docs are [here](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios_guide#objects-updating/iOS), but I'm having trouble applying it to this use case.

**Code:**

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    if ([PFUser currentUser]) {
        NSLog(@"User is logged in");

        PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
        NSString *userId = [PFUser currentUser].objectId;

        //userId[@"parent"] = [PFUser currentUser];

        [currentInstallation setObject:userId forKey: @"userId"];
        [currentInstallation saveInBackground];

    } else {
        NSLog(@"User is not logged in");
        //[welcomeLabel setText:@"Not logged in"];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to store a point to an object in parse is by saving the entire object to it. So don't store the `userId` in an `NSString`. Simply do the following:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    if ([PFUser currentUser]) {
        NSLog(@"User is logged in");

        PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
        PFUser* user  = [PFUser currentUser];

        [currentInstallation setObject:user forKey: @"userId"];
        [currentInstallation saveInBackground];

    } else {
        NSLog(@"User is not logged in");
        //[welcomeLabel setText:@"Not logged in"];
    }   
}
```

This will cause parse to save a pointer to the user as you want.